# How does TypeScript know about the behaviour of the length field in custom array types?

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, interface

When you create a custom array type using an interface, and give it the field `length: number`, TypeScript seems to somehow calculate the length of the array by itself, but if you leave the field out of the custom type definition, it no longer works.

What exactly is going on in the background here?

My code is:

```
interface IPerson {
    fullName: string;
    age: number;
}

class Person implements IPerson {
    fullName: string;
    age: number;

    constructor(fullName: string, age: number) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

interface IPersonArray {
    [index: number]: IPerson;
    length: number;
}

var personArray: IPersonArray = [new Person("Jane", 21),
                                new Person("John", 22)];

for (var i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(personArray[i].fullName);
}
```

Here's the most relevant part:

```
interface IPersonArray {
    [index: number]: IPerson;
    length: number;
}

var personArray: IPersonArray = [new Person("Jane", 21),
                                new Person("John", 22)];

for (var i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(personArray[i].fullName);
}
```

I'm only declaring the `length` field in the interface, but TypeScript magically figures out how the length field is supposed to work, and I get the output as expected. How does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't as magical as it might seem.

You add the definition for that field yourself in the interface `IPersonArray`, then you assign an array to `personArray`. TypeScript knows that an array has a `length` property, so the assignment is ok. And in run-time, the length-property of the array is called.

If you leave `length` out from your interface/type, you will not be able to access it, just like you can't access any of the other properties of the array that you happen to assign `personArray`.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have enough rep to upvote you though, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

In typescript, an interface is just a contract used in compilation-time.

If you were to compile a file filled with interfaces only, you'll get an empty (or almost empty) file.

What your code is doing is: defining an interface called `IPersonArray`, meaning that 
- every class implementing this interface should at least implement the `length` and `[]`.
- if you use this interface as var type, your var have access to `length` and `[]` only and the value assigned to this var should have a compatible type (exception is `any`).

JS's native array (which Typescript recognises) has `length` and `[]` so you can assign it to a var of type `IPersonArray`.

But... you could also have a code that pass through compilation but is completely wrong in run-time:

```
let anyType: any = { notLenght: ":scream:" };
let typedArray: IPersonArray = anyType;

let count: number = typedArray.length; // `undefined`, since there is `length` in `anyType`
```

By the way:

a. you can use generics for array: `Array<Person>` is equivalent to your interface `IPersonArray`

b. you can use `for of` to iterate over arrays in Typescript (depending on the version you're using)

```
for (let person of personArray) {
  console.log(person.fullName);
}
```

Comment: I just started learning TypeScript and haven't gotten to generics yet. Thanks for taking the time to write such an in-depth answer though, it really cleared up a lot of things for me!